# How to remove duplicate object based on condition from an array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object , I want to remove duplicate one based on 'documentTypeId' and 'flag' value. Here in below object I want to remove the object having 'documentTypeId' value is same and flag value is false. I tried but not getting proper filter. Please find the below code.

```js
const test = [{
    "id": 100,
    "documentTypeId": 3,
    "docName": "test",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "id": 31184688089,
    "documentTypeId": 1,
    "docName": "test2",
    "flag": true
  },
  {
    "documentTypeId": 3,
    "docName": "test3",
    "flag": true,
    "active": true
  }
]
const res = test.filter((value, index, self) =>
  index === self.findIndex((t) => (
    t.documentTypeId === value.documentTypeId && t.flag == false
  ))
)
console.log(res);
```

Comment: why dont you first filter out flag value false and then do the filter+findindex only for documentTypeId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your goal here is. You might be asking the question wrong. I think what you might be looking at is to remove duplicates from an array based on flags `documentTypeId` and `flag` with another condition that if there are duplicates you want to prefer the document which has `flag=true`.

You could try something like arranging all `documentTypeId`s in an array and sort them with boolean as first element and pick all `documentTypeId`s first element after the sort. Like below

```js
const filterFn = (arr) => Object.values(
    arr.reduce((acc, cur) => ({
      ...acc,
      [cur.documentTypeId]: [...acc[cur.documentTypeId] || [], cur]
    }), {}))
  .map(i => i.sort(({flag: a}, {flag: b}) => Number(b) - Number(a))[0]);
```

```js
const test1 = [{
    "id": 100,
    "documentTypeId": 3,
    "docName": "test",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "id": 31184688089,
    "documentTypeId": 1,
    "docName": "test2",
    "flag": true
  },
  {
    "documentTypeId": 3,
    "docName": "test3",
    "flag": true,
    "active": true
  }
]

const test2 = [{
    "docName": "test1",
    "active": true,
    "documentTypeId": 3,
    "flag": false
  },
  {
    "docName": "test2",
    "active": true,
    "documentTypeId": 1,
    "flag": false
  },
  {
    "docName": "test3",
    "documentTypeId": 5,
    "id": 5,
    "flag": false
  },
  {
    "docName": "test4",
    "active": true,
    "documentTypeId": 16,
    "flag": false
  },
  {
    "docName": "test5",
    "documentTypeId": 16,
    "id": 102,
    "flag": true
  }
]
const filterFn = (arr) => Object.values(
    arr.reduce((acc, cur) => ({
      ...acc,
      [cur.documentTypeId]: [...acc[cur.documentTypeId] || [], cur]
    }), {}))
  .map(i => i.sort(({flag: a}, {flag: b}) => Number(b) - Number(a))[0]);

console.log(filterFn(test1));
console.log(filterFn(test2));
```

Comment: For below array it is not working -

Comment: [{
  "docName": "test1",
  "active": true,
  "documentTypeId": 3,
  "flag": false
 }, {
  "docName": "test2",
  "active": true,
  "documentTypeId": 1,
  "flag": false
 },
 {
  "docName": "test3",
  "documentTypeId": 5,
  "id": 5,
  "flag": false
 },
 {
  "docName": "test4",
  "active": true,
  "documentTypeId": 16,
  "flag": false
 },
 {
        "docName": "test5",
        "documentTypeId": 16,
  "id": 102,
  "flag": true
 }
]

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER check now. hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

```
const data = [
  {
    "id": 100,
    "documentTypeId": 3,
    "docName": "test",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "id": 31184688089,
    "documentTypeId": 1,
    "docName": "test2",
    "flag": true
  },
  {
    "documentTypeId": 3,
    "docName": "test3",
    "flag": false,
    "active": true
  }
];

let typeMem = [];
let filtered = data.filter(({ flag: f, documentTypeId: d }) => 
  f || (typeMem[d] = (typeMem[d] || 0) + 1) && typeMem[d] < 2);

console.log(filtered);
```